# How to get mouse coordinates in Javascript under Adobe Air Extension for Dreamweaver 3.3?

Tags: javascript, css, html, air

this is my first post over here, but I am quite desperate. I Googled, Googled, and Googled again, without success. I would seriously appreciate any help or hint.

I am developing an Adobe Air app (a 2D puzzle/action HTML4 + CSS + Javascript game with an embedded level editor, for Windows). In fact, my game is almost finished and it runs very well in both IE9 and Chrome; however, I want to port it to Air (for many reasons), so I installed the Adobe Air Extension v.3.3 for Dreamweaver and followed the Adobe tutorial on getting started for creating an Air app from HTML project.

I can generate the .air file without any problem, however it seems that my game is freezing right at the start. I verified many, many, many things (not to say ALL); I also put various alert("works-check_1"); through all bits of my code, and it works well (but slow) in Dreamweaver... but the .air file load everything down to the footer, and then freeze before being able to draw a second frame. *I came to the conclusion that the problem is most probably originating from the current script I use in my .html file to get the mouse coordinates (that allows drag-and-drop in the level editor).*

Here is the script I currently have in the  section of my .html file:

```
<script language="JavaScript1.2">
var IE = document.all?true:false;
if (!IE) document.captureEvents(Event.MOUSEMOVE)
document.onmousemove = getMouseXY;
var tempX = 0;
var tempY = 0;
function getMouseXY(e) {
if (IE) { // grab the x-y pos.s if browser is IE
tempX = event.clientX;
tempXb = event.clientX + document.body.scrollLeft;
tempY = event.clientY + document.body.scrollTop;
}
else {  // grab the x-y pos.s if browser is NS
tempX = e.pageX;
tempY = e.pageY;
}
document.getElementById("xcoord").value = tempX;
document.getElementById("ycoord").value = tempY;
return true;
}
</script>
```

It seems that Adobe Air is unable to use that, and breaks. **Is there any other easy way in HTML/Javascript that I can get the X and Y mouse coordinates on document.mousemove, that Air will allow?**

Answer (score 0):

Ok nevermind, this bit of code works like a charm in Air. My game was freezing because I had to use this syntax:

```
setTimeout(alert('Timeout'), 10);
```

instead of this one:

```
setTimeout("alert('Timeout')", 10);
```

**("") is not supported by Air security measures; it prefers a function to be passed, than a string.**

French reference: http://help.adobe.com/fr_FR/AIR/1.5/devappsflash/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118666ade46-7f0e.html

Uhm! However, even if my game now compiles in .air and works fine, it works terribly slower than directly in IE9, Chrome or Safari. On Safari though, to get lighting-fast Javascript performance, I had to disable EVERYTHING in Preferences > Security, except the "Allow Javascript". Air performance is very, very similar to the performance I had on Safari BEFORE disabling those security options. And by the way, Titanium Appcelerator gives me the VERY same Javascript performance (framerate) as Adobe Air, for my game. I prefer Air to Titanium, but I have to find another IDE solution in order to compile my game with a fast and embedded Javascript engine, and also to be able to port to other platforms.... I am desperate! I want to port on other platforms with **at least** the same speed as in IE9, Chrome or tuned Safari... nothing lives up to my expectations, all IDE are currently slower than the results I get directly within the browsers, and this should be equivalent :(